# awk -f does not work with piped content

Tags: awk, pipe, gawk

```
$ cat > test.txt <<EOL
Beam goes blah
John goes hey
Beam goes what?
John goes forget it
Beam goes okay
Beam goes bye
EOL
$

# works
tail -f test.txt | awk                      '/Beam/ {print $3}'

# does not work
tail -f test.txt | awk -f CERTAINLIB.AWK -e '/Beam/ {print $3}'

# does not work either
awk -f CERTAINLIB.AWK -e '/Beam/ {print $3}' < <(tail -f test.txt)
```

Could you help to comment why `awk -f` does not work with piped content, and the possible workaround ? Many thanks !

It turns out the problem comes from CERTAINLIB.AWK, which filters incoming text...

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Are you using GNU `awk`. Standard `awk` does not have an `-e` option... Also, what does that other `awk` code do?

Comment: Nothing is displayed. Yes, gawk is used on WSL1 Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, I certainly can't reproduce what you're (not) seeing, using GNU `awk` and a `CERTAINLIB.AWK` containing `{ print }`.  Is that other `awk` program calling `next` for each line of input, or remove all `Beam` strings?

Comment: @Kusalananda I am very sorry. It is the CERTAINLIB.AWK in my PC that pre-filters the incoming text.

Comment: So it may be removing the data that your `/Beam/ { print $3 }` code would have caught?

Comment: Exactly as you diagnosed :D

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) tell us that you're using WSL! That is very relevant. ii) show us the contents of `CERTAINLIB.AWK`, we can't help you debug something if we don't know what it is.

Comment: @terdon Can this question be closed ? The problem is solved with the help of Kusalananda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/583046/awk-f-does-not-work-with-piped-content?noredirect=1#comment1085593_583046).

Rather than being an issue related to reading piped input, the `CERTAINLIB.AWK` code removed the data that the `-e` expression would have outputted.